# Data Templated ListBox not stretching Horizontally - again

Tags: listbox, datatemplate, silverlight-5.0

Can't get my horizontal ListBox with 'Data Template' to stretch fully.
I researched this topic and the most popular answer is to set the ItemContainer Style like :

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
                </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the fully XAML code.  The ListBox.ItemsSource = ObservableCollection

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>


        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <Button Margin="-2,-2,-4,-2"  >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>

 <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                 Height="50"  
                 Background="Red"
                 ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanel}" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Headers}" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>   
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: You're using a horizontal `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`. a horizontal `StackPanel` will NOT stretch it's contents horizontally. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Simply a user defined list of headers that shows on top of a content control and stretched to fit the screen space.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is difficult to do if you really want to use data-binding with a ListBox (or in fact any ItemsControl).

The reason is that there is no standard panel that works like a StackPanel but stretches its elements in the layout direction.

I don't even know of any third-party panel that does that (which makes me sometimes wonder what it exactly is that toolkit providers are for). I have a small marker in my mind to write one myself next time I need it, because it's easy to do if you're already familiar with developing panels.

If you are not, you are probably better off with creating a Grid programmatically.

I assume you have a variable number of elements (otherwise you could just define each in xaml and wouldn't need a ListBox).

Instead of using a ListBox with data binding you could also programmatically create ToggleButtons in a Grid along with the GridColumns all set to being star-sized.

Of course you could also just change your design and have the buttons be left-justified.

I know that this is a nuisance, but that's how it is.